# C# replacing "Random" text with string (wildcard)

Tags: c#, string, random, replace, wildcard

i want to replace this string: "color":"efea27", with "color":"0000ff",
but the "efea27" could be anything (its random). i want to change that to what the user inputs. for example 0000ff how do i do that when i dont know what is between the color "" ?

(its this file i want to edit: pastebin.com/JWzJQcVm )

Thanks!
-shinevision

Comment: so you want to replace the second value that is between " " with "0000ff" no matter what was there initially?

Comment: Is it JSON??? If so, use a json parser!!

Comment: Alex: yes i want to change "randomText" with my own

Comment: Bas: yes its json! what is a json parser?

Comment: Since it is json I suggest you use [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) a very popular json library for C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) like this:

```
var newColor = "hello";
var jtoken = JObject.Parse("{yourinput}");

var colorProperties = jtoken
                      .Descendants()
                      .OfType<JProperty>()
                      .Where(x => x.Name == "color")
                      .ToList();

foreach (var prop in colorProperties)
{
    prop.Replace(new JProperty("color", newColor));
}
var result = jtoken.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

As other comments have said, you will need to add the nuget package if needed with : `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`
And add the relevant namespaces:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
```

This code will change all occurrences of the "color" property throughout the input, regardless of it's hierarchy, which may or may not be something you desire.

Comment: You may need to install the nuget package: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1`

Comment: It worked! but there is one problem. :/ it isnt all on one line. is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Thanks, if you mean that you want to put the json into your code as a literal string, then to span multiple lines you'll need to mark it as a verbatim string, but prefixing it with @, like: `@"this"` You'll still need to escape quotes, but with double quotes ("") rather than backslash (\")

Comment: i want it to save it as a .json again and that it is all one 1 line :)

Comment: Ah, check my updated version, notice the `ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)`

Comment: Awesome! i changed it to Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None and it worked! **thank you so much!!**

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Depending on the modularity you want, this will do the job quickly. But it is not very handy if your context is more complicated than you original post looks like:

```
var yourColor = "\"Color\":\"efea27\"";
var split = yourColor.Split(':');
split[1] = "YourOwnText";
yourColor = String.Join(":", split);

Console.WriteLine(yourColor); // "Color":"YourOwnText"
```

Basically, stores in an array the key and the value of your original string, replaces the value by yours then joins them with the ":" as separator.

## Option 2

I never use this [feature](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) of Json.Net but it should do the job. To use it, you will need to install the nuget dependency:

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1`

If I have time, I will try to write something with it (here are some [tips](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)).

Comment: it works but i want to open a json file and the change all the colors to the input. is that possible?

Comment: Can you provide the whole Json ?

Comment: Yep. here it is:http://pastebin.com/JWzJQcVm (in the json file its all on 1 line)

Comment: You should add the JSON in your question so anyone can see it clearly ^^.

Answer (score 0):

A Regex replace should be able to do what you want:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

//Matches: "color":"######" where #'s can be A-F and 0-9
Regex r = new Regex("\"color\":\"[a-fA-F0-9]{6}\"");

//Example input (will be your JSON)
string json = "some stuff \"color\":\"efea27\" more stuff";

//Color to replace original with
string newColor = "\"color\":\"FF0000\"";

//output is: some stuff "color":"FF0000" more stuff
json = r.Replace(json, newColor);
```

To make it a bit more reusable you can do something like this (just replace the string "0000FF" with your input):

```
string replaceFormat = "\"color\":\"{0}\"";
json = r.Replace(json, string.Format(replaceFormat, "0000FF"));
```

Note that this will replace all occurrences of "color":"######" in the string.